# Logic Function Mod5 Problem

Tags: math, logic

I am looking for a solution:

A= {0,1,2,3,4};

F(x) = 3x - 1 (mod5)

Could you help me to find the inverse. I am struggling with this as it seems to be not to be onto or 1to1.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not 1-1? What do you get when you plugin 0 through 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x = 2y + 2`, where `y = F(x)`

-> 3x - 1 = 3(2y+2) - 1 = 6y + 5 = y (mod 5)

**edit:** if you want this to be evaluated for the list of principal values mod 5 [0,1,2,3,4], just evaluate 2y+2 for each of these, and what you get is [2,4,1,3,0]. Which, if you plug back into 3x-1, you get [0,1,2,3,4] as expected.

Comment: This was not what I was looking for. Sorry for my  poor explanation.

You have to take x from the set A.

Comment: SO when it comes to the first one 0:
f(0) = 3 * 0 - 1 (mod5)
That is my problem, as you can interpret mod5 in two ways. I tried in Java and it gives me -1 where mod interprets it as a remainder. But i am confused, as in Logic you can see mod as a absolute. Therefore it -1 = 1.

Comment: **NO** modulo is not an absolute value. If you want the principal value of -1, you get -1 + 5 = 4.

Comment: can you be elaborate about your answer please ? I still do not get why you add 5? It seems to work out. And what do you mean with principal value?

Comment: @bpr: you should read up on modular arithmetic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic -- strictly speaking, mod N is a congruence relation. The principal value (the wikipedia article uses "common residue") is the least non-negative value, e.g. between 0 inclusive and N exclusive; there are infinitely many solutions for x ≡ C (mod N). You can add any multiple of N to one solution, and thereby obtain another solution.

Comment: This only works because 3 and 5 do not share a common non-trivial divisor, right?

Comment: yes, 3 and 5 are relatively prime, therefore 3 has a multiplicative inverse mod 5.